# Error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'Appium' and platformName 'Android'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, appium-android

When I try to run my application using nodejs. I get above error into appium server

test.js file

```
var wd = require("wd");
var appDriver = wd.remote({
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4723,
})

var config = {};

config.android19Hybrid = {
   automationName: 'Appium',
   browserName: '',
   platformName: 'Android',
   platformVersion: 19,// API level integer, or a version string like '4.4.2'
   autoWebview: true,
   deviceName: 'any value; Appium uses the first device from *adb devices*',
   app: "D:\\market-deliveryboy\\platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\app-debug.apk"
};

appDriver.init(config.android19Hybrid);
```

Error I get on Appium server

```
[debug] [MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [{"automationName":"Appium","browserName":"","platformName":"Android","platformVersion":19,"autoWebview":true,"deviceName":"any value; Appium uses the first device from *adb devices*","app":"D:\\market-deliveryboy\\platforms\\android\\app\\build\\outputs\\apk\\debug\\app-debug.apk"},null,null]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1554729359484 (18:45:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1554729359486 (18:45:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find a driver for automationName 'Appium' and platformName 'Android'. Please check your desired capabilities.
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.getDriverAndVersionForCaps (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:205:11)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.getDriverAndVersionForCaps [as createSession] (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:268:66)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\basedriver\driver.js:301:19)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at AppiumDriver.executeCommand (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:420:26)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at executeCommand (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:352:34)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at asyncHandler (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:489:15)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at next (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at next (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at logger (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\morgan\index.js:144:5)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at next (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:130:5
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:224:16)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at done (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:213:7)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Ravindra.N.Bhanderi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:273:7)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:182:13)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1086:12)
[debug] [MJSONWP]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I try to solve that but not get success. I'm bigger in  Ionic + Appium testing. If you have any solution for this then It's very helpful for me.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing this parameter -- automationName: 'Appium', worked for me, as automationName anyway defaults to Appium.

Comment: It makes sense, but after I will try your ANSWER I get another error "Unable to find an active device or emulator with OS 19".

Comment: Does your platformVersion match the OS version on your device/emulator? What happens if you don't provide this parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem with installing the uiAutomator2 driver for android.
https://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/quickstart/uiauto2-driver/
command - > 'appium driver install uiautomator2'

(If you are using ios device -use this driver appium-xcuitest-driver
command - > 'appium driver install xcuitest'
)